# working with the book inventing python games

Tags: python

I am working with my 11yr old and the book "Invent your own computer games with Python. We have copied the program Guess the number from page 23 and can't get it to run. I am so sad since we have already struggled and only have ran 3 simple programs.
here is the program

```
#this is a Guess the number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print('Take a guess.') # four spaces in frnt of "print"
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') # eight spaces in front of "print"

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if gues == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessTaken + 1)
    print('Good job, ' +myName + '! Your a the cats meow, ' + You guessed my number in' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

        if guess != number:
          number = str(number)
          print ('Nope not even close. the number I was thinking of was ' + number + '.')
```

We are always getting errors.
Mostly with line 12
for guessesTaken in range(6):
seriously I have no idea why this isn't working. Please help.

Comment: Please [edit] and add the specific errors you are getting.

Comment: im already seeing a lot of typos, ill try and list them out in a moment

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This code is not minimal.  You failed to post the error message.  There is no apparent attempt to diagnose the problem yourself.  Did you refer to the language tutorials, or look up the error messages on line?

Comment: @Ironkey: please do not use Stack Overflow to correct typos; we do not want the site used as a proofreading service.

Comment: Side note: a quick search came up with the website for that book. Use it to copy-and-paste or download the code instead of re-typing.  Most prgramming books have sites where you can download the code and get fixes. http://inventwithpython.com/invent4thed/

Answer (score 1):

I rooted out most of the typos

here is a working version of the game, maybe look into learning the basics before immediately working w/ games!

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print('Take a guess.') # four spaces in frnt of "print"
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') # eight spaces in front of "print"

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken + 1)
    print('Good job, ' +myName + '! Your a the cats meow, ' + 'You guessed my number in' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
```

here's what was wrong, and what you should look out for in the future:

strings: always enclosed with " " if you forget one of the quotations nothing will work

variable names: always make sure to check you're using the right ones, and define good ones so you don't get mixed up!